# Is it possible to get polymorphic deserialization in JSON.Net without the "$"?

Tags: mongodb, json.net

I'm serializing objects and storing them in a MongoDB database, which doesn't allow keys that start with '$'. I require polymorphic deserialization, which JSON.Net supports by adding a variable named "$type". I can get around this by simply storing the object as a string, but then I lose the ability to do any sort of filtering/querying on the stored data using Mongo.

Is it possible to change that name to something compatible with MongoDB?

Comment: Can you explain how you use json.net in this context? Why don't you store a strongly typed object in MongoDB? MongoDB itself supports polymorphic deserialization...

Comment: That's interesting. I didn't know that. That could be a good solution.

Comment: I'll elaborate that in an answer to show some samples....

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `BsonDiscriminatorAttribute` to support [polymorphic serialization in MongoDB's C# driver](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/serialize-documents-with-the-csharp-driver/#polymorphic-classes-and-discriminators). The topic can be quite complex, so it makes sense to consult the documentation regarding registration of class maps, scalar and hierarchical discriminators, etc.

In the simplest case, it will look like this:

```
[BsonDiscriminator(Required = true)]
[BsonKnownTypes(typeof(Cat))]
public class Animal { ... }

public class Cat : Animal { ... }
```

Now, if you store a `Cat` like

```
db.GetCollection<Animal>("Animal").Insert(new Cat());
```

you will see

```
db.Animal.find();
> { "_id" : ObjectId("..."),  "_t" : "Cat" }
```